# Wordpress thousand of categories crashing site

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance, crash, cpu

I have a big website, at the moment i have about 10k unique visitors daily, I have 2000 categories, 12k Tags, 36k custom taxonomies.

It's not a design flaw, as its a website to watch online movies, I used, categories for Seasons and stuff like that, the custom taxonomies are Actors, regizors etc.

The problem is that my hosting keeps crashing with 100% processor, the resources cannot be an issue, as i have my own server with 4xXeon, 64 GB ram.

I have isolated the problem, and it's due to very slow queries for example, what are my options? :

```html
# Time: 160830 17:01:20
# User@Host: razvypp[razvypp] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 9.159090  Lock_time: 0.001680 Rows_sent: 30  Rows_examined: 420117
SET timestamp=1472565680;
SELECT  wphn_posts.ID
    FROM  wphn_posts
    INNER JOIN  wphn_term_relationships 
            ON (wphn_posts.ID = wphn_term_relationships.object_id)
    WHERE  1=1
      AND  ( wphn_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (3630,
                        4955,4956,4957,4958,4959,4960,4961,4962,4963,4964,4965,
                        4966,4967,4968,4969,4970,4971,4972,4973,4974,4975,4976,
                        4977,4978,4979,4980,4981,4982,4983,4984,4985,4986,4987,
                        4988,4989,4990,4991,4992,4993,4994,4995,4996,4997,4998,
                        4999,5000,5001,5002,5003,5004,5005,5006,5007,5008,5009,
                        5010,5011,5012, ... (hundreds of numbers) ...,49740,49779)
```

Here is a dump of the tables

```html
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.4.15
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: 30 Aug 2016 la 15:17
-- Versiune server: 5.5.51-log
-- PHP Version: 5.5.37

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `trolio`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structura de tabel pentru tabelul `wphn_posts`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wphn_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `movie_type` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text NOT NULL,
  `post_excerpt` text NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
  `comment_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `ping_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `post_password` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to_ping` text NOT NULL,
  `pinged` text NOT NULL,
  `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content_filtered` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
  `post_mime_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `views` int(99) NOT NULL,
  `views_this_week` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `imdb` double NOT NULL,
  `imdb_votes` float NOT NULL,
  `imdb_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `fb_shares_root` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `movie_name` varchar(140) NOT NULL,
  `season` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `episode` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `serial_id` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structura de tabel pentru tabelul `wphn_term_relationships`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wphn_term_relationships` (
  `object_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `term_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structura de tabel pentru tabelul `wphn_term_taxonomy`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wphn_term_taxonomy` (
  `term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `term_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `taxonomy` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` longtext NOT NULL,
  `parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `wphn_posts`
--
ALTER TABLE `wphn_posts`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191)),
  ADD KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  ADD KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  ADD KEY `post_author` (`post_author`),
  ADD KEY `serial_id` (`serial_id`),
  ADD KEY `episode` (`episode`),
  ADD KEY `season` (`season`),
  ADD KEY `movie_name` (`movie_name`);

--
-- Indexes for table `wphn_term_relationships`
--
ALTER TABLE `wphn_term_relationships`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`object_id`,`term_taxonomy_id`),
  ADD KEY `term_taxonomy_id` (`term_taxonomy_id`),
  ADD KEY `term_order` (`term_order`);

--
-- Indexes for table `wphn_term_taxonomy`
--
ALTER TABLE `wphn_term_taxonomy`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`term_taxonomy_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `term_id_taxonomy` (`term_id`,`taxonomy`),
  ADD KEY `taxonomy` (`taxonomy`),
  ADD KEY `parent` (`parent`),
  ADD KEY `count` (`count`),
  ADD KEY `term_id` (`term_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `wphn_posts`
--
ALTER TABLE `wphn_posts`
  MODIFY `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `wphn_term_taxonomy`
--
ALTER TABLE `wphn_term_taxonomy`
  MODIFY `term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: I guess you get that list of numbers from a table also. Join against that table instead of using `IN()`

Comment: the query is from wordpress core, that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"Rows examined" = 420K -- That smacks of a missing index.

Probably missing:

```
INDEX(term_taxonomy_id, object_id)
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the two tables.

What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size=20GB

I have just checked, all indexes are set.

Comment: "all indexes"??  Keep in mind that the 'composite' index I recommend is different than separate indexes in each column.

Comment: The indexes are wordpress default, i haven't altered them in any way.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can discuss them.  And (I think) you can add indexes to WP tables.

Comment: OK, that index is present.  There is essentially no reason to mention `wphn_posts` in that query; can you remove it?  Can you provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.